# Bot Service Chat Interface Not Responding

Tags: botframework

Working with 'xuba-sched' bot deployed to Azure.  The bot is running and responding normally via SMS/Twilio integration.

However, when I click into the Bot Service and attempt to interact with the bot via the built-in Chat Interface I see no responses in the chat panel.

This had worked previously.